# how to get data from other table to one table and show it?

Tags: select, sum, case, average

```
table1
no   | date    | 
J001 | 06 June |

table2
no   | code | qty |  /// AVGprice | Total
J001 | B001 |  5  |  /// 1500     | 7500
J001 | B003 |  7  |  /// 1000     | 7000

table3                                   table4
code | name        | AVGPrice            no   | code | Price
B001 | procc       | 1500                M001 | B001 | 1000
B002 | motherboard | 2000                M001 | B002 | 2000
B003 | VGA card    | 1000                M002 | B001 | 2000
                                         M002 | B003 | 1000
```

I get AVGprice from this query

```
select t.code, t.name, t.avg
from (select table3.code, table3.name, (
         select avg(table4.price)
         from table4
         where table4.code=table3.code)as 'avg'
      from table3
)as t
```

result that i can make is

```
no  | date    | Info   
J001| 06 June | ABCDEFG
```

with these query

```
select t.no, t.date, t.info
from (select table1.no, table1.date, 'ABCDEFG' as info
      from table1
     )as t
```

result that I want is

```
no  | date    | Info     | Total
J001| 06 June | ABCDEFG  | 14500  --> from sum of Total
```

I don't know where to put my avg query and how to sum it...

Answer (score 0):

The following should add the subquery you need to pull the average, and I added another column that
gives you the sum of the averages.

```
select t.no, 
t.date, 
t.info, 
(select avg(table4.price)
         from table4
         where table4.code=table3.code)as 'avg',
sum(avg)
from (select table1.no, table1.date, 'ABCDEFG' as info
      from table1
     )as t
 group by t.no, t.date, t.info
```

Comment: I added the sum of the averages, but that may not be what you wanted. You can just change it to what you want summed up there.

Comment: unknown column table3....should i put it --> from table4,table3 ?? and sum...it show same with first avg 1500, not like 2500 where sum of avgprice for B001 and B003